# Multi-field sorting in Laravel 5.5

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, sorting, laravel-5.5

- I just start with Laravel 5.5 recently. And I got stuck at Sort function.
- I have  at the view and use onchange function so User can choose sort asc/desc.
- The point is how i can sort by price of product after User searched by name or after sorting by category?
- I have search and don't understand how can send parameters on URL in Laravel. How to I post it on route/URL? How can I take it to use in Controller?

---

View:

```
<select id = "sorting" name = "sorting" class="form-control selecting" onchange="Sorting()">
    <option value="normal">Sort by Price</option>
    <option value="asc">Price Ascending</option>
    <option value="desc">Price Descending</option>
</select>
```

Javascript:

```
function Sorting() {
   var sorting = document.getElementById('sorting').value;
    if(sorting == "asc")
    {
        window.location.href="{{route('product-management.asc')}}";
    }
    if(sorting == "desc")
    {
        window.location.href="{{route('product-management.desc')}}";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use HTML forms in order to POST data to a certain URL, see https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp.

If you don't want to use HTML forms, you can use AJAX requests. See https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp

Btw, I recommend you to use sorting on the client-side, this is less complex and won't use unnecessary resources.

Comment: Thanks, I just start programing so don't understand about "on the client-side". If i put it in form, it will auto submit whenever user change the <select> to sort ?

Comment: What you want to achieve is that a user is able to sort certain data on a certain click, right? From what I understand is that you're trying to do this by sending a request to your server, sorting the data and then respond with the sorted data and then render the data onto your screen, right? I think this is unnecessary whilst you can sort the data straight away with just a some JavaScript. See this basic example: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_sort.asp

Comment: Oh, okay. Thanks Garre. I will try that

Comment: If you feel comfortable with jQuery, you should try DataTables.js. Works Great! You can reorder any column and even offers pagination. I use it in my own Laravel projects.

Comment: @kaori What is your solution? Please mark any answer for future readers :)

Comment: Well, my solution is very simple, everytime user click choose Asc or Desc in dropdown, the page will refresh and add parameters like ?order=price&sort=asc. And then in controller I write a function to check it and return to view with sort result